# Arrangements of numbers when each can have multiple values?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I feel as though this is fairly straightforward, but I can't figure it out.

If I have $n$ numbers, clearly these can be arranged in $n!$ ways. But if each of the $n$ numbers can have a value $v, \text{where } 0\le v<k$ then each has $k$ possibilities. If $n_1 := k'$, this says nothing of whether $n_2$ may also be $k'$.

In the case $k = 10$, this is the decimal number system; so the number of combinations is $10^n -1$.

Can this be generalised to $k^n - 1$? I'm suspicious at the lack of any factorial.

Comment: No reason for suspicion, the number is $k^n$. No subtraction of $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks - I forgot about good ol' zero!

Comment: It is pretty tiny, easy to forget. We have $k$ choices for the first entry, and for every such choice we have $k$ choices for the second entry, and so on.

Comment: Yes, now you say that it does seem stupid and obvious. Thanks! If you can be bothered to rewrite as an answer, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: There is no real need for a formal answer, you know precisely what's going on.